# Add invited guest user to group in Azure AD

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to send a fresh user an [Azure AD invite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and then add them to a [specific security group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using the Microsoft Graph API.

The invitation sends perfectly and in the response body, I get the ID of the new user. When I try to add that user to the security group, though, I get the following 403 error message:

> Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

I should have the correct API Permissions granted for the app because I have Group.ReadWrite.All set from the Azure portal.

According to [this](https://www.eliostruyf.com/adding-guests-to-an-office-365-group-via-the-microsoft-graph-api/), I should be able to add the invited user to the group without issue but I'm worried that maybe a guest user would be considered a "personal Microsoft account" and adding them to the group from the Graph API is unsupported:

[image: personal account permission]

Here's my request:

```
POST /v1.0/groups/dXXXXXXX-cXXX-4XXX-9XXX-7XXXXXXXXXXX/members/$ref HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer {my token}
Content-Length: 102
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Content-Type: application/json

{"@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/9XXXXXXX-9XXX-4XXX-9XXX-9XXXXXXXXXXX"}
```

How do I add a freshly invited guest to a group?

**Update:**

I'm getting the same insufficient privileges error when using the API to put a user from my tenant into the group so it looks like the issue isn't specific to guest users.

**Update 2:**

As requested, here's the full token request:

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 979
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=authorization_code&client_id={clientID}&scope=user.read%20email%20openid%20profile%20offline_access&code={code}&redirect_uri={mywebsite}&client_secret={secret}
```

**Update 3:**

Screenshot of my permissions:

[image: Azure AD app permissions]

And the scope from my decoded access_token:

```
"scp": "Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.ReadWrite.All email Group.Read.All 
    Group.ReadWrite.All openid profile User.Invite.All User.Read User.ReadWrite 
    User.ReadWrite.All"
```

Comment: You are getting that error because of wrong scope rest of the thing is okay. your token does not contain `User.Invite.All and  Directory.ReadWrite.All` permission

Comment: Hi see the updated answer. And kindly delete all of your comment its become a long tail. Let me know if you have any more concern.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - please see the comment from yesterday that hasn't been deleted.

Comment: So now its working? See Update: 2 As Per Authorization Code Flow. Let me know your update

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - No, it isn't working. As I've stated from the beginning, the token comes back with `User.Invite.All`, `Directory.ReadWrite.All`, and `Group.ReadWrite.All` but the request still fails.

Comment: Just follow my steps and remember you need `dedicated permission` as you are trying `authorization code flow` make sure you have clicked `grant admin consent`. Let me know your update.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - Admin consent has already been granted and the token comes back with the correct permissions as you mentioned. It's giving me the same message.

Comment: Would you kindly update your question with permission screen shot and token decode. Its very easy but I am wondering where you are doing wrong. Let me know how can I remotely assist you.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - I updated the question as requested.

Comment: Could you also add application permission for `User.Invite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All` along with dedicated permission

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron - What do you mean by "application permission"? I have `User.Invite.All` and `Directory.ReadWrite.All` set in Azure's API permissions per my screenshot.

Comment: opposite of Dedicated permission while you click add permission, just beside the dedicated permission tab. also add it. You do have skype or anything I can remotely fix?

Comment: Any progress or do you need any more help?

Answer (score 3):

As per my understanding, first you need to invite your `guest user` like below:

**Request Url:** `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations`

**Method Type:** `POST`

**Body Format:**

```
{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "example@anydomain.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://myapp.com",
  "userType":"member"
}
```

**Permission Required:** Dedicated `User.Invite.All`

**Post Man Example:**

[image]

> Once you have successfully add it. after that you have to add that
>   user in a group like below:

**Add Guest User To Group:**

**Request Url:** `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/b4699e9c_GroupId_cee27b53/members/$ref`

**Method Type:** `POST`

**Body Format:**

```
{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/Guest_User_Id"
}
```

**Permission Required:** Dedicated `Directory.ReadWrite.All`

**Post Man Example:**

[image]

**Note:** Would you kindly add `User.Invite.All` and also `Directory.ReadWrite.All` permission and try again. I have successfully done all the steps and got success.

**Point To Remember:**

Once you have `Directory.ReadWrite.All` you need not to add `Group.ReadWrite.All` separately.

**Update**

Make sure you have click on `Grant Admin  Consent` Button after adding permission
See the screen shot below:

[image]

**Update: 2 As Per Authorization Code Flow**

Since you are using authorization code grant. You need to add dedicated permission on azure portal. Then try to get `authorization code` like below

**Get Authorization Code:**

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={ClientId}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirectURI}&response_mode=query&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

**Request Token oauth2/V2.0/token:**

*Request URL:* `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/V2.0/token` Or `https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/V2.0/token`

*Method:* `POST`

*Request Body Format*

```
client_id:Your_Clinet_Id
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
redirect_uri:Your_Portal_Redirect_URI
grant_type:authorization_code
client_secret:Your_Client_Secret
code: Paste Code Here
```

**Decode Token:**

You could decode your token on https://jwt.io/

your permission should look like this:

[image]

Comment: When decoding the access token, I get this: `"scp": "Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.ReadWrite.All email Group.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All openid profile User.Invite.All User.Read User.ReadWrite User.ReadWrite.All"`